# When I switch one activity to another activity then inApp purchase dosen't work

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, onclicklistener

```
 ////// in first Activity 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==btn){
        Intent i= new Intent(ChatActivity.this ,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name",0);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
//////////// in second activity oncreate method
Intent i=getIntent();
int name=i.getIntExtra("name",10);
demo(name);

   ////// in demo method
private void demo(int name) {
    if(name==0){

    purchase();
    }
}
////// in purchase method

public void purchase(){
    bp.purchase(MainActivity.this,PRODUCT_ID);
    showToast("in purchase Method !!!");
}
```

inApp purchase all classes include in my application but first  statement not working  and second is working.If I separate run second class without switch work properly.plz help.

Comment: is your onClick method of first activity working?

Comment: yes onClick working and switch to another activity. but control comes to next activity demo method working and control goes to purchase method but first statement not working and second is working

Comment: Add a log message and check whether correct value of "name" is being passed from onClick of button, check the value of name variable in second Activity

Answer (score 0):

Change your onClick() method as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()== btn){// this can be also used as v.getId() == R.id.btn
        Intent i= new Intent(ChatActivity.this ,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name",0);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.